# Connectedness of both $Y \cup A$ and $Y \cup B$ where $A, B$ is a separation of $X -Y$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $Y\subset X$ be such that both $X$ and $Y$ are connected. Show that if $A$ and $B$ is a separation of $X-Y$, then $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected.

I found a proof for this problem in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44807/to-show-that-x-times-y-setminusa-times-b-is-connected). Here it is:

> Here is my attempt for QN2 I think to prove it by contradiction, assume $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are not connected then for $P$ and $Q$ disjoint $Y\cup A=P\coprod Q$ and for $M$ and $N$ disjoint $Y\cup B=M\coprod N$ $(Y\cup A)\cup (Y\cup B)=(P\coprod Q)\cup (M\coprod N)$. The left side will give $X$, and the right side can be written as a disjoint union, this contradicts the fact that $X$ is connected, so $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ must be connected

Now, I find that there is a logical gap in the proof which is. The proof shows us that: it can't happen that $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are **both** not connected. So at least one of the two subspaces are connected. But it doesn't show that **both** are. How to overcome this obstacle?

Any ideas?

Comment: There are other proofs around for this problem, see for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736457/question-on-connectedness-topology-by-munkres-23-12

Answer (score 1):

You may show

> If $A$ and $B$ is a separation of $X−Y$, then $Y∪A$ and $Y∪B$ are connected.

by assuming

> $A$ and $B$ is a separation of $X−Y$ and $Y∪A$ **OR** $Y∪B$ is not connected

and then derive a contradiction.

You do not show above statement by assuming

> $A$ and $B$ is a separation of $X−Y$ and $Y∪A$ **AND** $Y∪B$ is not connected

and deriving a contradiction.

---

An attempt for a proof could be:

Say $X-Y=A+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are $(X-Y)$-open (i.e. $A$ and $B$ are a separation of $X-Y$)
and say $Y\cup A$ NOT connected (this should lead to a contradiction).

Say $Y\cup A = P + Q$ is a separation (i.e. $Q$ and $P$ $(Y\cup A)$-open)

Then $P\cap Y=\emptyset$ or $Q\cap Y=\emptyset$ (since $Y$ is connected)

Say $P\cap Y=\emptyset$

Then $Y\subset Q$
and 
$$\begin{aligned}
X &=A\cup Y\cup B\\
  &=P + (Q \cup B)
\end{aligned}$$

But still $P$, $Q$ and $B$ are not said to be open in $X$ like
$$X=P' + Z$$
where $P'$ and $Z$ are $X$-open and disjoint - what is $P'$ and $Z$?

Comment: Right. but the proof provided in that answer only shows that $Y\cup A$ or $Y\cup B$ IS connected. This is not enough to prove the statement, is it?

Comment: Yes, and it is clear that the outcome of that proof is not as desired since the assumption is "$Y∪A$ **AND** $Y∪B$ is not connected" instead of "$Y∪A$ **OR** $Y∪B$ is not connected". Perhaps you could just do the correct assumption and try to adapt above proof to derive a contradiction or you could try your own proof (drawing images for your intuition might also help).