# If $X$ and $Y$ are connected, topological spaces with at least two points, prove that $X\times Y-(x,y)$ is connected for a fixed $(x,y)\in X\times Y$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

The question is in the title. I am aware that there are questions about the same setting only not for specific points but rather proper subsets (i.e. [Prove that $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214317/prove-that-x-times-y-setminus-a-times-b-is-connected)). The solutions seem to be using connected components, which I haven't learned yet. I am hoping that someone could provide an easier solution considering that we are in a special case of the linked problem.

I have proven that: If $X,Y$ are connected, their product $X\times Y$ is connected and I know that if I could find a continuous surjective function from $X\times Y$ to $X\times Y\setminus\{(x,y)\}$, then I would be done. However, I am unable to do so. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44807/4280) has good answers (without components) that can be applied for $A=\{x\}$ and $B=\{y\}$ too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f: X\times Y \backslash \{(x_0,y_0)\} \to \{0,1\}$ be a continuous function. Let $x_1 \in X \backslash \{x_0\}, y_1 \in Y\backslash \{y_0\}$ and $(x,y) \in X\times Y \backslash \{(x_0,y_0)\}$.

Let us assume $x \neq x_0$. Then, $z \in Y \mapsto f(x,z)$ is a continuous function from $Y$ to $\{0,1\}$. Since $Y$ is connected, this function is constant and $f(x,y) = f(x,y_1)$. Then, the function $z\in X\mapsto f(z,y_1)$ is a continuous function from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$ so by the same argument it is constant and $f(x,y) = f(x,y_1) = f(x_1,y_1)$.

If $x_0 = x$, then $y\neq y_0$ and the same line of reasoning gives $f(x,y) = f(x_1,y) = f(x_1,y_1)$.

We have shown that every continuous function from $ X\times Y \backslash \{(x_0,y_0)\}$ to $\{0,1\}$  is constant, therefore $ X\times Y \backslash \{(x_0,y_0)\}$ is connected

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice solution!