Connection of complementary of set
In a certain exercise I have been asked to show that if $X,Y$ are connected sets and $A,B$ are non trivial subsets of $X,Y, A \not= X, B \not=Y$, then $(X \times Y) \setminus (A \times B) = (A \times B)^c$ is connected.

I have been struggling my head much time and I don't know how to reach the answer. What I most tried is using the property that if the latter set wasn't connected, then there would exist a function $f : (A \times B)^c \to \{0,1\}$ (with the discrete topology) such that $f$ is continuous and onto. Could somebody give me a hint?

Your question is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44807/if-x-and-y-are-connected-then-x-times-y-setminusa-times-b-is-connecte
